# print embeds in discord.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

This is a follow-up question to [discord.py-blank-messages?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62382561/8851394)

This is my code:

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    log = "\n[MESSAGE] [{0}] <{1}>\n----\n{2}\n----".format(message.guild, message.author, message.content)
    print(log)
```

Which will print out something like this:

```
[MESSAGE] [Example_Server] <User#0001>
----
Lorem Ipsum
----
```

However, when embeds from bots are sent, this is the output:

```
[MESSAGE] [Example_Server] <Open Bump#1081>
----

----
```

I want to print the message that the bot sent in plain-text.

**I have heard that this is because the bot is sending embeds, and that the `log` cannot print embeds. Is there a way to print embeds (by converting them into plain text) to the console?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get a list of embeds in a message with the `.embeds` attribute. This returns a list of `Embed` objects, which you're then able to access the individual description, title, fields etc.

Edit this as you wish, but the example just prints the main description:

```py
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    embed = ""
    if len(message.embeds) != 0:
        embed = message.embeds[0].description
    log = "\n[MESSAGE] [{0.guild}] <{0.author}>\n-----\n{0.content}{1}\n-----".format(message, embed)
    print(log)
```

---

**References:**

- [`Message.embeds`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Message.embeds)
- [`discord.Embed`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Embed) - Find the embeds' attributes here.

Comment: Thanks! Works PERFECTLY! :) This has been a problem for a previous few weeks.

Comment: No worries! Good luck with the rest of your bot :^)