# Custom Discord Bot | Commands | embeds

Tags: python, discord.py, bots

I want to create a /duty and /off duty command which then opens up a embed in the discord channel, I want the embed message show the time they did /duty and the time they did /offduty. This is for fivem PD duty logs. I already have my main bot set up. just need the code to do the command and embed message. I need the code to make the embed, which consists with the actual time the did the /duty command.

to solve this problem and to do /duty and /offduty

I’m new to this app, so please help.

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import os
from keep_alive import keep_alive

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="/", intents=discord.Intents.all())

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Success: Bot is connected to Discord")



@client.command()
async def ping(ctx):
    await  ctx.send("Pong!")

token = os.environ.get("Token")
keep_alive()
client.run("my token is here ")
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [print embeds in discord.py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62385286/print-embeds-in-discord-py)

Answer (score 2):

You can learn how to customize embeds here: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?#embed

Here is some basic code of commands sending an embed with the timestamp using the datetime module. Add this to your code.

```
import datetime

@client.command()
async def duty(ctx):
  embed = discord.Embed(description="example",timestamp=datetime.datetime.now()) #create the embed
  await ctx.send(embed=embed) #send the embed

@client.command()
async def offduty(ctx):
  embed = discord.Embed(description="example",timestamp=datetime.datetime.now())
  await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```